# How do I write multiple output files using CoRB?

Tags: xquery, marklogic-corb, sjs

By default when I run a CoRB job that returns data from the process function that data is streamed into a single file on the CoRB client.  I have a problem where I need to write the output to different files, one file per URI that is being processed.  How do I write CoRB outputs into multiple files instead of one large file?

I have a CoRB job that returns the URI today, and those URIs are streamed together into one output file with each URI on a new line.  I would prefer to have a directory filled with files, and have one file per URI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CoRB has two built-in Tasks that can be used to write the output of the **PROCESS-MODULE** to the filesystem.

- `ExportBatchToFileTask` Generates *a single file*, typically used for reports. Writes the data returned by the **PROCESS-MODULE** to a single file specified by **EXPORT-FILE-NAME**. All returned values from entire CoRB will be streamed into the single file.
- `ExportToFileTask` Generates *multiple files*. Saves the documents returned by each invocation of **PROCESS-MODULE** to a separate local file within **EXPORT-FILE-DIR** where the file name for each document will be the based on the URI.

It is common for people to write CoRB jobs to generate a CSV and other reports that append the output of the [**PROCESS-MODULE**](https://github.com/marklogic-community/corb2#PROCESS-MODULE) execution into a single file.
If you specify the [**EXPORT-FILE-NAME**](https://github.com/marklogic-community/corb2#EXPORT-FILE-NAME) option, then [CoRB will automatically use ExportBatchToFileTask](https://github.com/marklogic-community/corb2/issues/130) by seting the [**PROCESS-TASK**](https://github.com/marklogic-community/corb2#PROCESS-TASK) option for you (unless you have explicitly set the **PROCESS-TASK** option):

```
PROCESS-TASK=com.marklogic.developer.corb.ExportBatchToFileTask
```

However, if you would prefer to have the results of each process module execution saved as it's own output file, for a multi-threaded download/export, then you would want to configure the `ExportToFileTask`. It will use the URI sent to the process module to construct a directory structure an filename, and save the results of the transform to that file path.

You can set the [**EXPORT-FILE-DIR**](https://github.com/marklogic-community/corb2#EXPORT-FILE-DIR) to provide a base directory in which to write out those files.

So, to configure CoRB to write the results of each PROCESS-MODULE execution to it's own file, you would want to have the following options set for your CoRB job:

```
PROCESS-TASK=com.marklogic.developer.corb.ExportBatchToFileTask
EXPORT-FILE-DIR=/tmp/export
```